# Javascript : Sorting a table that contains objects

Tags: javascript, sorting

I wanted to know if there is a better way to sort a table than this solution that works perfectly.
My goal is to move the element to index 0 if the value is equal to "xx";

```js
const countries= [
    {label: "Germany", value: "DE"},
    {label: "France", value: "FR"},
    {label: "Spain", value: "ES"},
];

countries.forEach(element => {
    if (element.value === "FR") {
        const france = element;
        countries.splice(countries.indexOf(element), 1)
        countries.unshift(france);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sort` - return `-1`/`1` (depending whether it is `a` or `b`) for your XX, and returning `0` for everything else will keep the original order.

```js
const countries= [
    {label: "Germany", value: "DE"},
    {label: "France", value: "FR"},
    {label: "Spain", value: "ES"},
];

const result = countries.sort((a,b) => a.value === "FR" ? -1 : b.value === "FR" ? 1 : 0);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  I was thinking something similar, but return 0 is "FR"..   But looking at the data it would seem logical that value is unique anyway..

Comment: Without the `b.value` check, this fails on Firefox, and moreover it's semantically necessary that if `a.value` is `"GB"` and `b.value` is `"FR"`, the callback must return 1, not 0, if it's going to return -1 when they're the other way around. I've taken the liberty of fixing it.

Comment: Probably less readable, but you can also do `const result = countries.sort((a,b) => (b.value === "FR") - (a.value === "FR"));`, since `true` gets converted to `1` and `false` gets converted to `0`. ;-)